# Issue with chromedriver while running robotframework tests

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I get the below error message when I try to run the roboframework tests.
Script:

```
def Myfunc():
    for element in Group1.copy():
        if (str(element)[0:2] == Atype):
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(options)
            driver.get("https://example.com/")

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn response
  (Session info: chrome=119.0.6045.200)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6C2628EF2+54786]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C2595612]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C244A64B]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C244EEC1]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C245115F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C2451250]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C248B424]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C248B91C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C24C6D87]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C24ABEAF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C24C4D02]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C24ABC43]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C2480941]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C2481B84]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6C2977F52+3524194]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6C29CD800+3874576]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6C29C5D7F+3843215]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6C26C5086+694166]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C25A0A88]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C259CA94]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C258CC83]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFEFFAA26B1+33]
```

I am on Chrome Version 119.0.6045.200 (Official Build) (64-bit)
and ChromeDriver 118.0.5993.70. (I couldn't not find 119v)

Please let me know what is the issue and how can I resolve this.
Thank you!!

Comment: [unknown error: result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn response (Bug): · Issue #13084 · SeleniumHQ/selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/13084)

Comment: It doesnt explain clearly how its been resolved. Updating chrome driver to which version? I do not find any chrome driver that is 119x version. Or please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: on [chromedriver.chromium.org](https://chromedriver.chromium.org) you can see [the Chrome for Testing availability dashboard](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) and there is `v120` and even `v121` and `v122` (but I would use stable `v120`). And maybe you should manually run `chromedriver` in console/terminal to check if it works. `chromedriver -v` should show you what version you use.